# Obtaining a single value from a table in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe: `trainData`. Running `table(trainData$Survived)` I obtain the following table.

```
  No  Yes 
1062  490
```

How can I obtain **just the integer value relative to the `No` column**?
Running this:

`pNo = table(trainData$Survived)['No']`

I still obtain a table in `pNo`:

```
  No 
1062
```

While I would like to have only `1062`! How to do that?

Comment: Try `unname(table(trainData$Survived)['No'])` or `table(trainData$Survived)[['No']]`

Comment: Thanks @markus ! That solved my problem: if you make ti an answer to my question I will mark it as the correct one :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `[[`:

Example:

```
table(iris$Species)[["setosa"]]
# [1] 50
```

Answer (score 0):

You got a named vector. If you don't want the name 'No', try the as.numeric() method to convert it:

```
pNo <- as.numeric(table(trainData$Survived)['No'])
pNo
```

Comment: A small technical note: table() output is not a vector but an array in this case one dimensional.  See for example: `dim(table(iris$Species))`, vectors don't have a dim attritbute.